# C# - Web API 2 - How to define a JSON Formatter that depends on HTTP Request Header

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I'm currently developing a Web API RESTful service which is aimed to expose the business layer of a C# application which already exists.

Indeed, the company wants the UI to be rewritten in AngularJS by another development team.
So, the AngularJS code will call my Web API in order to create, read, update and delete some data.

The data payload will be exchanged through JSON format.

We would like to manage **time zone.** The UI might be in the future used by customers from different countries. But for some reason, the database (which exists for years) has simple datetimes encoded on local server timezone, and this will not happen to change.

So, the idea is that the client interface adds a Timezone-Offset in the HTTP header for any request. Let's say:

> Timezone-Offset: 120

means UTC+2 time zone.

The idea is to modify the Web API so that, when it deserializes datetimes (which are expressed in client time zone), it converts them automatically to `DateTime` objects whose value has been modified to represent the value in server time zone, according to the time zone offset that was in the request header...

Depending on where the DateTime comes from, I had to modify two mechanisms:

- The model binding: I created a class implementing `IModelBinder` (this is used when a `DateTime` is simply in the querystring)
- The JSON formatter: I created a class implementing `JsonConverter` (this is used when a `DateTime` is inside a JSON structure in the request body)

**With the `IModelBinder`**, it was pretty simple because there is such as method:

> public bool BindModel(HttpActionContext actionContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)

So, I could get the request through the `actionContext`, and then get the time zone offset from it.

**But the problem comes with `JsonConverter`.** I implemented the method:

> public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)

in order to deserialize `DateTime`, but in the context of that method, there is no way to know about the current context, and therefore the request header (and therefore, the time zone offset...).

**I tried many solutions**, and the one that is currently working, but is quite ugly, is that I applied an `AuthorizationFilterAttribute` to the controller. This is called before the deserialization mechanism starts, and inside that filter, I can modify the JSON formatter this way:

> actionContext.ControllerContext.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.Converters.Add(new TimeZoneJsonConverter(offset));

But it raises two problems:

- First, `AuthorizationFilterAttribute` was designed to handle authorizations... I sort of hacked it, but I did it because it's the only filter that is actually triggered before binding/serialization, so I can tell the Json formatter the time zone offset to apply before it's too late...
- Secondly, there seems to be a dangerous issue, because when modifying `actionContext.ControllerContext.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.Converters`, I firstly thought that it would be in the scope of the current Controller only, which is created and destroyed on every HTTP request. But I figured out that in fact, the settings are attached to a ControllerContext, and the latter is somewhat like static (didn't dig further, though), and is shared by instances of controllers... So, multiple clients with different time zones, would clearly end up into bugs...

**So, my question is...** Is there a way to define a JSON formatter that depends on HTTP Request Header. If the formatter is aware of the request, then the formatter would be able to get the time zone offset from the header, and correctly deserialize datetimes according to it...

Thank you for reading!

Comment: I tried going down this path, once.  It's much easier to simply make every datetime UTC server-side, and allow the client to display the date in the users timezone.  Anytime the client sends a date to the server, it first converts it to UTC with TZ offset information embedded.

Comment: I would avoid the JSON formatter (it doesn't seem like the appropriate place), and would instead use a custom filter.

Comment: check out https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.filters.iactionfilter(v=vs.118).aspx

Comment: ActionFilter is called after de-serialization (model binding), so it won't help in my case. See the Web API pipeline: [link](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/aspnet/888/aspnet-webapi-message-lifecycle)

Comment: Thanks for your comment, Amy, but it doesn't really answer my question. I'd like to modify the formatter to manage datetimes at this level... My question is, is that even possible? How to achieve it?